# how to get image from local path in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, image-uploading

all i am using angularjs Mean stack Application and my db is Mongo db .

i do image upload and retrieve functionlity. now done upload image into local folder inside the public like eg:upload. Now i need to retrieve the image through uploaded image folder path but i tried  get a error look like this anyone can help how to solve that issuse

Thanks

## Error

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/nodeprojects/Latest/upload/file-1491895250074.png
```

## Controller

```
$scope.Unitvalues = [{
    UnitId: "1",
    UnitName: "CONTROL",
    Icon: "http://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/sebin/r/j/icon-hospital-readmissions.png"
},
{
    UnitId: "2",
    UnitName: "GENERAL SURGERY",
    Icon: "localPath not Working"
}];
```

## HTML

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="UnitDrag in UnitDrags" id="doublew">

<li <img ng-src="{{UnitDrag.UnitIcon}}" alt="Loading" height="30" width="30"/>
</li>
```

Comment: run a local server maybe?

Comment: i try from http same error anyother solution

Comment: when i click that path in browser image will show